# Playing sound using Python

Tags: python, macos, audio, wav, playsound

Basically I'm trying to write a code that opens a sound file using python, but all I get is this error. using MacOS and Python 3.10. tried many solutions but no luck.

This is the code I’ve  tried first:

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound('/Users/cairo/Desktop/i wish.mp3')
```

```
    /Users/cairo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/bin/python /Users/cairo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py 
playsound is relying on a python 2 subprocess. Please use `pip3 install PyObjC` if you want playsound to run more efficiently.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cairo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    playsound(r'/Users/cairo/Desktop/beep sound 2')
  File "/Users/cairo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playsound.py", line 244, in <lambda>
    playsound = lambda sound, block = True: _playsoundAnotherPython('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python', sound, block, macOS = True)
  File "/Users/cairo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/playsound.py", line 223, in _playsoundAnotherPython
    raise PlaysoundException('Cannot find a sound with filename: ' + sound)
playsound.PlaysoundException: Cannot find a sound with filename: /Users/cairo/Desktop/beep sound 2

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've installed pip3 install PyObjC through the Terminal but it keeps showing the error.
what seems to be the problem?

EDIT:
tried this one:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

song = AudioSegment.from_wav("/Users/cairo/Desktop/i wish.mp3")
play(song)
```

Those are the errors I get:

```
/Users/cairo/PycharmProjects/beepsound/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydub/utils.py:170: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
/Users/cairo/PycharmProjects/beepsound/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydub/utils.py:198: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cairo/PycharmProjects/beepsound/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    song = AudioSegment.from_wav("/Users/cairo/Desktop/i wish.mp3")
  File "/Users/cairo/PycharmProjects/beepsound/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydub/audio_segment.py", line 808, in from_wav
    return cls.from_file(file, 'wav', parameters=parameters)
  File "/Users/cairo/PycharmProjects/beepsound/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydub/audio_segment.py", line 728, in from_file
    info = mediainfo_json(orig_file, read_ahead_limit=read_ahead_limit)
  File "/Users/cairo/PycharmProjects/beepsound/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydub/utils.py", line 274, in mediainfo_json
    res = Popen(command, stdin=stdin_parameter, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1847, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffprobe'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I would appreciate any help

Maybe python isnt the right PL for the job?

Comment: "*Cannot find a sound with filename: /Users/cairo/Desktop/beep sound 2*" ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

not a solution to your problem, but an alternative.
I had the same problem and playsound seems to be broken as it is relying on python 2.7.

You can use [pydub](https://pypi.org/project/pydub/) as an alternative.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

song = AudioSegment.from_wav("path/to/file.wav")
play(song)
```

Comment: Still not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use pygame to play the sound

https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted

`pip3 install pygame`

```py
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("file.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

Comment: i've tried that but no luck so far.

Comment: What's your issue @Oughtly? What error you are getting?

Comment: @Oughtly are you on windows machine? because pygame works different in windows I think; not sure

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error, and resolved on Mac - You need to also install PyObjC

There is a small line printed that reads
"playsound is relying on a python 2 subprocess. Please use `pip3 install PyObjC` if you want playsound to run more efficiently."
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufwlh.png)

If you install PyObjC, it works successfully.